# From swagger editor able to get the JWT auth token, but from application which enabled swagger-ui using springfox is not working

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, swagger-ui, springfox

Tested my auth server from swagger editor and is working fine. I'm able to get the token and authorization is happening without any issues. But, when I tried to integrate it with my web service where swagger UI is enabled using springfox dependencies is not working.

Success form swagger editor
[image: editor]

Failed from application
[image: application]

Noticed that in the failed case, swagger UI is sending only a single POST request, but swagger editor had an OPTIONS & POST request to get the token.

Suspected CROS filter initially, so I took my swagger json and tested in swagger editor and it worked.
My auth server and resource server with application is also working fine when tested via curl.

Sample auth server and resource server is this:- https://github.com/ranjithap7576/OAuth2-JWT

And swagger configuration is below

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfigNew {

@Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
private String clientId;
@Value("${security.signing-key}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${security.oauth2.authserver}")
private String authLink;

@Bean
public Docket api() {

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package")).build().groupName("test")
            .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
            .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.DateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));

}

private OAuth securitySchema() {
    List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = newArrayList();
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all"));
    authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));
    List<GrantType> grantTypes = newArrayList();
    GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(authLink + "/oauth/token");
    grantTypes.add(creGrant);
    return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);

}

@Bean
UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return new UiConfiguration("validatorUrl", // url
            "none", // docExpansion => none | list
            "alpha", // apiSorter => alpha
            "schema", // defaultModelRendering => schema
            UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS, false, // enableJsonEditor => true | false
            true, // showRequestHeaders => true | false
            60000L); // requestTimeout => in milliseconds, defaults to null (uses jquery xh timeout)
}

@Bean
public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
    return new SecurityConfiguration(clientId, clientSecret, "", "", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/user/**"))
            .build();
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[3];
    authorizationScopes[0] = new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all");
    authorizationScopes[1] = new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all");
    authorizationScopes[2] = new AuthorizationScope("write", "write all");
    return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("oauth2schema", authorizationScopes));
}

// @Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

I'm using springfox 2.7.0

Comment: Same discussed in https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2137

Comment: Your first image is Swagger UI 3.x, the second image is 2.x. This looks like an issue with the old version. Can you use the latest Swagger UI from the [official repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)?